# Why does this scheme get the error "Inconsistent hierarchy during C3 merge"?

Tags: perl, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

```
use parent qw<File::Spec::Unix File::Spec::Win32>;
```

And what--if anything--can I do about it?

- Okay, I understand that `Win32` inherits from `Unix`, but the dispatch is `Win32 -> Unix` and I want the `Unix` implementations as default until I override it and dispatch to the Win32 implementation my self.
- I also understand that because `File::Spec::x` just passes around class names, that inheritance is not a huge issue, but I have to wonder what would happen if I actually needed some classes to coordinate this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to default to File::Spec::Unix in generally and specifically use File::Spec::Win32, you do not want to use multiple inheritance.  File::Spec::Unix already inherits from File::Spec::Win32, so you've set up a (mostly) diamond inheritance which C3 does not want to resolve.

```
   Unix
   /  \
Win32  |
   |   |
  YourCode
```

You simply want to inherit from File::Spec::Unix and then use File::Spec::Win32 as desired.

```
package My::FileSpec;

use parent qw(File::Spec::Unix);
require File::Spec::Win32;

sub devnull {
    my $class = shift;
    return $class->File::Spec::Win32(@_);
}
```

If you want to get clever, you can eliminate the wrapper method.

```
*devnull = File::Spec::Win32->can("devnull");
```

Finally, you can put that into a loop to avoid repeating yourself.

```
my @Win32_Methods = qw(devnull tmpdir);
for my $method (@Win32_Methods) {
    my $code = File::Spec::Win32->can($method);
    die "File::Spec::Win32->$method does not exist" unless $code;

    no strict 'refs';
    *{$method} = $code;
}
```

You can override `isa` to claim you're a File::Spec::Win32 as well as a File::Spec::Unix but that's not really true and would probably be more confusing than useful as your class only acts like Win32 for a handful of methods.  Also, File::Spec has no object so it's practically not going to come up.

Overriding `can` is not necessary, it will return the correct code references.

Comment: I thought the virtue of c3 was that it *had* a resolution order, that you could override as needed and that it avoided the diamond-of-death by having a scheme for resolution order. Your last solution is basically how I handled the dispatch. And yes, as I said, checking isa doesn't seem to be a problem in this case. My point about ISA was not that I needed it (but in a similar case, I *might*) but that the lack of an isa relationship calls "equivalence" into question. Thanks. I still want to know more about what exactly this message means, in order to pick an answer.

Comment: @Axeman C3 aside, there's no need to inherit from FS::Win32. You're only selectively using its methods and there's no way via inheritance to tell which methods you want. The lack of an isa relationship is more correct as your class does not really behave like FS::Win32. The most correct thing you could say is your class isa File::Spec. As for C3, I believe the issue is one of your parents is also your grandparent. C3 says that "no class will appear before any of its subclasses". Having Unix first means it must appear before its subclass, Win32. If you reverse them, it "works".

Comment: thanks. Go ahead and put that in your answer and I will accept this. My understanding of c3 was simply as a ordered breadth-first linearization as opposed to the depth-first resolution of classic Perl. However, I read this from the Dylan paper: "A linearization that observes local precedence order will not produce a linearization which is inconsistent with the local precedence orders of any of the superclasses." http://192.220.96.201/dylan/linearization-oopsla96.html The difference being that c3 is trying to get a *trustable* automatic behavior--and I don't trust MI schemes.

Comment: I think what I missed is that it's not simply an ordered linearization, but a specific *heuristic* as well. Trying to guess that because a subclass is more specialized that's the behavior I would more likely want fails in this case--and I have to write more deliberate--what I call--"stapling" code because the scheme imposes a heuristic to "save" my effort which ends up costing me more effort. Of course this is likely an outlier case, but I think *textbook* C3 comes off a little less "perlish" as a result.

Comment: I think more perlish is that if the mro engine detects "non-strict c3" as above, it errors when you try multimethods: "Multimethods (or 'next') only supported under strict c3." I'm going to "fix" (YMMV) this, by writing "Class::Stapler": "staple catfile => 'File::Spec::Unix' ...`

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, this makes no sense. You don't have something that's a unix path and a Windows path.

Practically, this makes no sense either. There is no function in ::Win32 that's not in ::Unix.

File::Spec already abuses inheritance, and you're taking it a leap further. Inheritance is not what you need here!

Anyway, this would be equivalent to what you have, minus the error:

```
use parent qw( File::Spec::Unix );
use File::Spec::Win32 qw( ); 

sub isa {
    my ($self, $class) = @_;
    return $class eq 'File::Spec::Win32' || $self->SUPER::isa($class);
}
```

Comment: @ikegami, first I'll worry about what makes sense, second It's the ISA-relationship that I'm looking for, so your solution is also "minus" that relationship. And again, regardless of how pathological this particular case is (but actually, minus File::Spec itself the inheritance is actually quite simple). It seems that my homemade c3 routines might not have had the multi-dispatch capacity, but handled *basic* MI without telling me I can't inherit from two classes with the same methods.

Comment: @Axeman, Ignoring dubious unsupported claims of correctness, it will only change the relationship for calls to `->isa`. For all other intents and purposes, it does NOT change the relationship at all.

Comment: @Axeman, I've made an addition so that the relationship is completely preserved.

Comment: @Axeman, As for your homemade c3 routines, they were necessarily buggy if they handled having a class appear both before and after another class in the call chain without going into an infinite loop.

Comment: @ikegami: Like I said, they didn't do the nifty multi-dispatch, but they handled *simple* MI just fine. Problems like the diamond-of-death is pretty much a good indicator that MI cannot be done blindly--heck even single inheritance requires some delving at times. I had thought of overriding `isa`, but I know people who shriek in horror at overriding that or `can`--but I guess for interim code it works as well.

Comment: @Axeman, I don't know what you mean by "nifty multi-dispatch". I'm talking about the most basic of c3 inheritance. If `File::Spec::Axeman->non_existant` doesn't result in an infinite loop, your homemade "c3" isn't "c3" at all.

Comment: c3 is a *linearization* algorithm, whose purpose is to make a graph traversal *determinate*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization